# Only success handler is called - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Below is a part of my /authenticate method, which finds a user with the given `username` and `password`.

```
    User.findOne({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                type: false,
                "status": "401",
                "data": "Incorrect email/password"
            });
        } else {
            if (user) {
                console.log("token");
                res.json(generateToken(user));
            } else {
                res.json({
                    type: false,
                    "status": "401",
                    "data": "Incorrect email/password"
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

When there is no such `username` or `password`, by condition inside `if(err)` never fires.

Secondly, when i call this method from my angular-js code, regardless of `success/error` only success is called.

```
login: function (username, password) {
    return $http.post('http://localhost:8888/login', {
             username: username,
             password: password
    });
}
```

My Controller calling code:

```
AutheService.login(username, password).success(function(response) {
           console.log(response); // error message as well as success comes here
      }).error(function(data, status){
           console.log(data, status);
     })
```

Comment: Which version of AngularJS are you using? This issue sounds very familiar to something I've encountered before.

Comment: 2 possibilities. (1) Your 401 is invalid because it doesn't include a WWW-Authenticate header field as it should. (2) 401 errors don't trigger the error function. Try 403 Forbidden or 404 Not Found instead just to see if they work.

Comment: @Mike: When i change to 403, it again is handled in success handler

Comment: How does `User.findOne` relates to/used by  `AuthService.login`?

Comment: @NewDev: User.findOne is Query.. http://localhost:8888/login hits the login method which has User.fineOne Query firing

Comment: Are you by any chance using any `http interceptors`?

Comment: @yvesmancera: yes... i am using it...

Comment: Please update your question with your interceptor code. I think the interceptor might be the culprit.

Comment: Interceptors was my next suggestion - you have most likely "handled" the error in the interceptor's `responseError`, and so it becomes "successful"

Comment: Update the interceptor code..

Comment: @Shane, you don't have `responseError`?  And, in Dev Tools, can you check whether you indeed get `HTTP 401`

Comment: @NewDev: I do get 401 error response in my network tab

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));` in your response callback inside your interceptor? Is that being hit on errors? the `|| $q.when(...);` part looks suspicious.

Comment: @yvesmancera: That's being hit... below is the response {"data":{"type":false,"status":"403","data":"Incorrect email/password"},"status":200,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://localhost:3000/login","data":{"username":"asas@saas.com","password":"sasas"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"OK"}

Comment: @Shane, ah... so the actual response is 200? no wonder.. fix your server code to actually return HTTP 401

Comment: OK, the problem is definitely not in AngularJS but on your back-end, you're sending a 200 response with a JSON message containing the 403 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to respond with an actual error code on your server-side. I'm assuming you're using expressJS and after looking at their docs, you can chain your response like `res.status(401).json(...)`:

```
User.findOne({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
}, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(401).json({
            type: false,
            "status": "401",
            "data": "Incorrect email/password"
        });
    } else {
        if (user) {
            console.log("token");
            res.json(generateToken(user));
        } else {
            res.status(401).json({
                type: false,
                "status": "401",
                "data": "Incorrect email/password"
            });
        }
    }
});
```